# How to gain auto run permission on android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-permissions, bootcompleted

I am working on an alarm app on android, when the device reboots, alarm clocks which the user set before should be re-set, but when the app is in a stopped state, my boot receiver won't receive `Intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` any more so that alarm clocks can't be re-set.

I was wondering if I can gain auto run permission for my app? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: did you add  `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in your manifest file?

Comment: @Mr.7 of course i did...

Comment: go through this link http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html It might hlepful.

Comment: I have already try this way in my app... My point is that when user force kill app, the app will stay in stopped state, in this case receiver within the app won't receive any broadcast unless use FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES, but the key is how to deal with boot completed broadcast sended by the system.

Answer (score 0):

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
```

Have you added this `intent-filter` in your `receiver` class, You can quickly check by adding this with permission and then firing the event through ADB shell if it receives it.